# Showing php 5.5.9 when i installed 5.5.8 in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed php 5.5.8 in ubuntu but when i run info.php it is showing php5.5.9..what is going..

I installed phpmyadmin, mysql, apache2 also..

Can anyone tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version displayed is probably the good version, you can also get more information with `php -i` or `php -v` if you just want the version.